# Column limits for datastore upload

Tags: ckan

I'm running a pretty vanilla instance of CKAN 2.3, and am happily uploading CSV files into the datastore.

I then hit this error on one of my CSV files:

```
Error: CKAN DataStore bad response. Status code: 409 Conflict. At: http://localhost:8080/api/3/action/datastore_create. 
HTTP status code: 409 
Response: {"help": "http://localhost:8080/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_create", "success": false, "error": {"records": ["row \"1\" has extra keys \"Storm tide height (relative to highest astronomical t... 
Requested URL: http://localhost:8080/api/3/action/datastore_create
```

As it turns out, one of the column headings exceeded 63 characters. When I reduce the number of characters for that column, it uploads fine.

So, two questions:

1. Is there a hard limit for column headings for the datastorer function?
2. If so, is that configurable?

Much thanks for any assistance.

Comment: There would be no good reason for a 63 char limit. This is a bug. Please open an issue at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues and supply your example CSV. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't also remove certain characters from the column name when you reduced the number of characters? Also, there would appear to be an even smaller "limit" but it shouldn't lead to total failure: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3C895849.8010609@joeconway.com

Comment: Hi Matt. The only edit I made to get it to work was change (metres) to (m) in the heading of the last column. That changed it from 66 chars to 61.

Comment: This is from one of the contribs over https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2804: "The postgres maximum length for a column name is 63 characters, this probably isn't a coincidence. Not sure what could be done about it, other than warning the user." I think that's most probably the explanation. Do you think that constitutes an "answer"?